# What would be a suitable name for the game panel in tetris?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, computing

I am trying to develop a Tetris clone. However, I am unsure what to name the panel where the user places the pieces.

*Game panel* seems too generic since the entire frame is in fact the panel of the game. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [well](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/well#Noun)? The [shaft](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shaft)?

**Edit:** Wikipedia [suggests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetris#Gameplay) *the well* or *the matrix*, but also mentions *shaft*:

> A random sequence of tetrominoes (sometimes called "tetrads" in older versions) [...] fall down the playing field (a rectangular vertical shaft, called the "well" or "matrix").

The Tetris Wiki [has this](http://tetris.wikia.com/wiki/Playfield):

> The playfield is the grid into which tetrominoes fall, also called the "well" (common in older games) or the "matrix" (especially in more recent Tetris brand games). The playfield is surrounded by a frame called the tetrion, which controls the overall behavior of tetrominoes.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much anything will work as long as you are consistent:

- board
- window
- screen
- play area
- area
- rectangle
- box
- home
- foundation
- zone
- world
- grid

Other than that, just copy the name from someone else:

- field ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetris))
- well ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetris))
- shaft ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetris))
- matrix ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetris), [Tetris](http://www.tetris.com/how-to-play-tetris/beginner-tips.aspx))
- screen ([Vadim Gerasimov](http://vadim.oversigma.com/Tetris.htm))

Comment: I'm partial to "well"

Comment: I can never take the name "shaft" seriously.

Answer (score 0):

I always called it "the bucket".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'game panel' I would call it the 'arena'.

Answer (score -1):

What about simply 'game area'?

Comment: Again, this is a bit too generic since every area belongs to the game, and hence is a 'game area'.